# json file not saving my previous data

Tags: json, save, append, dump

So I have a simple program that puts data into json file. The problem I am having is that the file resets when I restart the program and add into it. How do I save the file so that next time I run the program it will just append to the previous data. Sorry a little new to python. here's my code:

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

vocabulary = defaultdict(list)

def update_vocabulary(category, value):
    vocabulary[category].append(value)

    with open("test.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(vocabulary, f, indent = 2)




while 1:
    input_category = input("give me a category ")
    input_value = input("give me a value for that category ")

    update_vocabulary(input_category, input_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "w" use "a" (append) mode with open function:

```
 open("test.json", "a") as f:
```